# Overriding QLabel widget in PyQT

Tags: excel, qt, pyqt4, qlabel

I am new to `PyQt` perhaps thats why facing this issue. I am trying to make a component inserter for excel sheets. For this purpose I am using QT for interface and using `Qlabels` within  parent class of `QMainWindow`. On the basis of item selected from `Qlist` Widget, few `Qlabels` have to change on `mainwindow` dynamically [Component inserter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So5Kk.jpg)

As can be seen in above picture, the labels like `WCAP-;` Part Number and all below needs to change dynamically when the selected items change(when select button is clicked). But what happening is if I choose a different item from list, the previous Label stays and the new label is overlapping it as can be seen from picture below [showing overlapping of labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DmuR.jpg)

The code below shows that whenever button "Select" is pressed", label2 (`Qlabel2`) is formed, how can i delete the previous label whenever select button is pressed so that new Label dynamically replaces the old label.

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
def Display(self):
    self.close()
    label1 = QtGui.QLabel("Select the sheet",self)
    label1.move(0,15)
    self.listwidget = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
    self.listwidget.move(0,40)
    self.listwidget.resize(150,150)
    for i in range(len(self.sheetnames)):
        self.listwidget.addItem("%s"%self.sheetnames[i])

    btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Select',self)
    btn.resize(50,50)
    btn.move(170,40)
    btn.clicked.connect(self.Selected)
    self.show()
def Selected(self):
    self.close()
    selecteditem = self.listwidget.currentItem().text()
    self.sheetindex = self.sheetnames.index(selecteditem)
    print self.sheetindex
    aa = self.loadsheet.sheet_by_name(selecteditem)
    global label2
    label2 = QtGui.QLabel("",self)
    label2.setText(selecteditem)
    label2.move(0,190)
    self.show()


    self.InputParameters(aa)
```

Answer (score 0):

You see a new `QLabel` because you create a new one every time you call `Selected`. I would initiate the UI at the creation of the widget (in the `__init__` method):

```
def __init__(self):
     self.label2 = QtGui.QLabel("",self)
```

And only update the text of the `Qlabel` when `Selected` is executed:

```
def Selected(self):
     self.label2.setText(selecteditem)
```

About reinitializing all labels with an unknown number of labels and removing the old ones, you might want to look at `QLabel.setParent(None)`. I wrote you a little example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class test(QtGui.QWidget):

     def __init__(self,parent=None):

         self.widget=QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

         # Button to add labels
         self.btnAdd = QtGui.QPushButton('Add')
         self.btnAdd.connect(self.btnAdd, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.btnAddPressed)

        # Button to remove labels
        self.btnRemove = QtGui.QPushButton('Remove')
        self.btnRemove.connect(self.btnRemove, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.btnRemovePressed)

        # List to keep track of labels
        self.labels=[]

        # Layout
        self.hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.btnAdd)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.btnRemove)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)   


        self.show()

    def btnAddPressed(self):

        """Adds a new label."""

        self.labels.append(QtGui.QLabel("lbl"+str(len(self.labels)+1), self))
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.labels[-1])    

    def btnRemovePressed(self):

        """Removes last label."""

        self.labels[-1].setParent(None)
        self.labels.pop(-1)


def main():

    #Creating application   
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_win = test()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: yeah I understand that but isn't there a way to delete previous QLabels on the go? further in the same program I have to create labels without knowing their total numbers in advance. If I know the number in advance then I guess it is easy but if I don't then is there a way to delete previous ones? Thanks for help